# Android Layout - Scale Images to stay always at same place in different resolutions

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create a custom top view using an`ImageView` where buttons stays always at the same position and scale in proportion of the resolution of the device. I have been trying to put my elements inside a `RelativeLayout` using margins without any success the button always move from it position and its not scaling.

How could achieve this?

This is the example I am trying to get for all resolutions:

[image]

and here my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/settings_red_btn"
            android:id="@+id/settings_btn"
            android:contentDescription="settings btn"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:layout_width="43dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/top"
            android:id="@+id/imageView17"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here :

1. You need to have the same padding right **in the images themselves** resources settings_red_btn & top. That way, you set to them alignParentRight = true, and they will align with the same padding.
2. You need to specify padding right for imageView17, according to screen resolutions. This is done by defining dimens.xml file on all resolutions. There are many blogs and stackoverflow hits on this. You can start with : http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/appendix-c-everything-about-sizes-and-dimensions-in-android/

Comment: I have tried using padding however, it stretch the image and the top image does not fit the screen

Comment: have you tried setting padding in all the resolutions ?

Comment: can you provide the images settings_red_btn & top ?

Comment: I have added the two images

Comment: your resources are all wrong. you need to create resource for each resolution and then create resource for the settings button, which has padding top and left within.

Comment: sorry, i can't help you with that.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway, I 6 different resolutions for each image in my drawable folder created with android drawable importer